# How to use single function for multiple inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

I would like to know how to use single method for both inputs in javacript.

I have a form having two input fields, calling a function to format currecny.
I need to know how to apply for same function for two different inputs.

```
  formatCurrency(e){
    var myinput = e.target.value;
      var val = myinput;
      val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');      
      if(val != "") {
        var valArr = val.split('.');
        valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
        val = valArr.join('.');
      }      
     document.getElementById("samount").value = val;
  }

  formatRCurrency(e){
    var myinput = e.target.value;
      var val = myinput;
      val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');      
      if(val != "") {
        var valArr = val.split('.');
        valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
        val = valArr.join('.');
      }      
      document.getElementById("tamount").value = val;
  }

  <input type="text" id="samount" name="samount" class="form-control"  @keyup=${this.formatSCurrency} >
  <input type="text" id="tamount" name="tamount" class="form-control" @keyup=${this.formatRCurrency} >
```

How to make a single function can be used for both inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `e.target` refers to the `<input>` you're operating on, so just change the

```
document.getElementById(...).value = val;
```

to

```
e.target.value = val;
```

and you'll be able to use the same function for both inputs. There's also probably no need for the `id`s anymore.

```
<input type="text" name="samount" class="form-control"  @keyup=${this.formatCurrency} >
<input type="text" name="tamount" class="form-control" @keyup=${this.formatCurrency} >
```

and

```
formatRCurrency(e){
  var value = e.target.value;
  value = value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');      
  if(value !== "") {
    var valArr = val.split('.');
    valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
    val = valArr.join('.');
  }      
  e.target.value = val;
}
```

(note that your `myinput` variable actually contains a *string*, not an `HTMLInputElement`, which may be confusing - best to use precise variable names)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is to scrutinise the target Element's `id` attribute and take action accordingly.  For example...

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    var targetID = e.target.id;

    switch(targetID) {
        case "samount":
            /* 'samount' specific process */
            break;
        default:
           /* 'tamount' specific process */
    }
}
```

If you wish to carry out the same process regardless of the active Element then the `event.target` property contains a reference to that Element...

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    var val = element.value;
    // process 'val' etc ....
    element.value = new_value;
}
```

Hope that helps. :)

- [switch @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)
- [event.target @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)